# Clearing "render cache" whenever a content type is edited in production environment (by coding) in Drupal 8

Tags: caching, drupal-8

In Drupal 8, when I edit a content type used in a taxonomy term which is in turn used in another node(page), the changes don't reflect on the page unless I clear the "render cache" manually.

I want to implement clearing the cache (all/specific) whenever I modify a node by coding. But the problem is twig doesn't accept PHP code. 
I'm all ears if anyone has a suggestion (better with some code) for this problem!

Answer (score 1):

To clear a particular type of cache after a node/taxonomy/block entity is edited, we can implement hook_form_node_form_alter() or hook_form_taxonomy_term_form_alter() or in general hook_form_alter(). We can clear cache inside by using specific form_id(s) or otherwise.
Here is an example for node with a specific node-type edit form:

```
function myModule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
    if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit' && ($form_id == 'myNode_edit_form') {
      $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'cache_form_submit_node';
    }
  }
}

function cache_form_submit_node($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  drupal_flush_all_caches();  //To clear all cache or

  $renderCache = \Drupal::service('cache.render');
  $renderCache->invalidateAll(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal by default caches every page. To avoid that while development you need to setup the development environment. You can follow these steps:

- Edit your settings.php file.

  > The code at the bottom of your sites/default/settings.php file should look like this:

  ```
  if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
    include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
  }
  ```
- Create settings.local.php file in sites/default folder

  > Copy copy sites/example.settings.local.php to sites/default/settings.local.php
- Modify debugging configuration

  > Take a look at the variables in sites/default/settings.local.php, specifically: uncomment these lines.

  ```
  # disable the CSS and JavaScript aggregation features
  $config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
  $config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;

  # disable the render cache
  $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';

  # Disable Dynamic Page Cache.
  $settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
  ```

  > Add this line to disable caching when not logged in.

  ```
  $settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';
  ```
- Enable Twig debugging options

  > Create a file development.services.yml in sites folder.
  >   To Enable Twig debugging Copy and Paste following code into it and save.

  ```
  parameters:
    http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
      twig.config:
        debug: true
        auto_reload: true
        cache: false  
    services:
      cache.backend.null:
        class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
  ```

Comment: Hi Razeem,
It is great indeed for the development environment. But I'm looking for the permanent solution for clearing cache on every modification to any node/entity while in the production environment. Please do share your insights. Thanks

Comment: It is better to write cache contexts for your code for doing that You can look for more of it in https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-api. Kill the cache each time is not a good method it downs your site performance. If still you chose that then you can use something like `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` to clear page cache **OR** `drupal_flush_all_caches();` To clear all cahes (That makes it too slow)

Comment: Thank you. All these are very good points. That is why I want to clear cache only when a **site administrator "changes any content type"** so that changes are reflected and cache are not deleted all the time.